# How do I initialize events when using Backbone.Marionette.Application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Marionette is great but some things can get a bit confusing to follow.  On my initial page load I show a Marionette.Layout in a region of a Marionette.Application.  But for some reason the click events are delegated but are not actually responding.  If I navigate to another route (removing the layout view) and then return to the route (re-rendering the view) then the events are active.  If I cause the view to be rendered twice in a row, then it works.  Maybe I'm initializing this system wrong.

```
var     ListView =  Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    el: "#listView", // exists on DOM already
    events: {
        // this is what is supposed to work
        // as well as events in my subviews
        "click" : function() { console.log("clicked");}
    });


var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.app = options.app;
    },
    start: function(page) {
        console.log("start...");
        // with silent false this causes list() to be called
        // and the view is rendered
        // but the ListView does not get its events delegated
        Backbone.history.start({
            pushState:  false,
            silent:     false
        });

        // only by running loadUrl here
        // do I get the events delegated
        // or by switching between other routes
        // and coming back to 'list'

        // but this is causing a second useless calling
        // of list() re-rendering
        console.log("loadUrl...");
        Backbone.history.loadUrl(page);
        // actually the events are not yet delegated at this point
        // if I pause a debugger here.
        // events only active after the  Application finishes its initializers
    },  
    routes: {
        'list': 'list'
    },
    list: function() {
        var lv = ListView({});
        this.app.focus.show(lv)
    }
});

var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

app.addInitializer(function(options) {
    this.router = new Router({app: this});
    this.router.start();
});

app.addRegions({
    // #focus does exist on the DOM
  focus: "#focus",
});

app.start({});
```

An alterative start that I expected would work but sadly doesn't

```
    start: function(page) {
        console.log("start...");
        Backbone.history.start({
            pushState:  false,
            silent:     true // don't trigger the router
        });

        // call the router here via history
        console.log("loadUrl...");
        Backbone.history.loadUrl(page);
        // causes page to be rendered correctly 
        // but events are not delegated
    },
```

I've stepped through it all with a debugger but still can't see what the magical effect of loadUrl is that causes it to work.

I've also tried just reinserting the layout into the region:

```
app.focus.show(app.focus.currentView)
```

Maybe there's a different way to structure this that would simply not run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is the answer, but...

If you're elements exist on the DOM already, and you are trying to attach a view to them, and attach that view to a region, using the region's `attach` method:

```
list: function() {
  var lv = ListView({});
  this.app.focus.attach(lv)
}
```

the `attach` method was created specifically for the situation where you want to use an existing DOM element. Calling `show` instead, will replace what's there, which may be causing the jQuery events to be released.

Comment: thanks for the answer Derick ! it sounds very likely that this will solve the issue.  I haven't had a chance yet to try it out but will get back and accept your answer shortly.

Comment: that didn't do it.  the method is attachView() but it doesn't render the view, so I still have to do show()

I've decided that I shouldn't be juggling the DOM so much with very little user end result.  so when the user paginates or changes search results then new results will come from the server and will be rendered and added to the list, but the ones already on the page from the first page load shouldn't be associated with views.  no gain in it.

Answer (score 0):

in the onRender section add

this.delegateEvents();

When Marionette closes a view it unbinds events as well. Events are only delegated when the view is initialized. When you show a previously stored view you will need to call the delegateEvents method again.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/714